# Connection issues with LocalDB

Tags: php, sql-server, localdb

I'm testing out a website I made in local environment, using Sql Server LocalDB as I said above. The site's done, now I wrote a php script that connects to the database and sends out some emails based on the database contents. I need this script to run automatically, so I've already set up a batch file in the Windows Task Scheduler to run automatically every hour. No problem in this. The issue is that sometimes (pretty often actually) the php scripts can't connect to the database. This seems to happen mostly when I recently "explored" my website, so my question is:

does LocalDB allow only one connection at a time?

If you have other ideas, please tell me. I need to finish testing ASAP.

Comment: What you have tried so far..?

Comment: I tried setting up the batch script to close the connections to the database before running the php script, but this doesn't work at all. Running the script twice in a short amount of time, the second run works better, but this may be only a coincidence. I don't know what else to try, right now.

Comment: Did you open and close the SQL buffer before and after the queries?

Comment: Yes, I did. Every page if the website is built in a master-page-like way, and the connection string, sqlsrv_connect($connection) and sqlsrv_close($connection) are both in the master page code, so every page opens and closes the connection for sure. the php script for sending emails open and closes, too. (edit: i mistakenly wrote sqlsrv_open instead of sqlsrv_connect in the comment here)